# Traverse Element to get values of XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

How to get values from XML? I came to this point:

```
Element rowsElemnt = tTRRecordMap.get("rows");
```

and I dont know how to go further

```
 <rows>
    <ns0:details>Postponement</ns0:details>
    <ns0:tutor>
       <ns1:domainId>Anna</ns1:domainId>
    </ns0:tutor>
 </rows>
 <rows>
    <ns0:details>Deletion of RE 1</ns0:details>
    <ns0:tutor>
       <ns1:domainId>Maria</ns1:domainId>
    </ns0:tutor>
 </rows>
 <rows>
```

If I paste my code to eclipse I can see a such tree

[image]

Comment: can you post the code you have tried

Comment: modifying/reading xml by manually selecting the recursive elements is tedious ... google for xpath-api .... reducing iteration-complexity